# Python using Fabric to connect to an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I'm learning **Fabric**. I want to achieve the following: **ssh into my EC2 machine and ls the home directory**.

I have started with the following:

```
from boto import ec2

from fabric.colors import green as _green, yellow as _yellow


class EC2Conn:
    def __init__(self):
        print(_green("Started..."))
        self.ec2conn = None
        self.user = 'fabUser'
        self.access_key = 'xxxx'
        self.secret_key = 'xxxx'

    def connect(self):
        print(_green("Connecting..."))
        ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1a")
        self.ec2conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(self.access_key, self.secret_key)

        print(self.get_instances())


    def get_instances(self):
        return self.ec2conn.get_all_instances()


def run_me():
    a = EC2Conn()
    a.connect()
```

But this gives me  a blank list [] I do have 1 instance running so this is incorrect.

Comment: Is it show any error?

Comment: no error it connects with the details but shows and empty []. when it should have 2 instances. I setup a new user and give them the correct permissions (full admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change little bit in your code as following

```
self.ec2conn = ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1', 
                  aws_access_key_id=self.access_key,
                  aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_key)

print(self.get_instances())
```

Or

```
region = ec2.get_region('eu-west-1')
self.ec2conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(self.access_key,
                  self.secret_key, region=region)

print(self.get_instances())
```

Remember that `ec2.connect_to_region` and `ec2.connection.EC2Connection` both returns `ec2.connection.EC2Connection` object. Refer [here](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connect_to_region)

Comment: top codes give me NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_instances' and the second does the same [] blank

Comment: Did you check the region? Is it correct? Check it with aws console.

Comment: In the console it states the available zone for the instance is eu-west-1a.

Comment: change `eu-west-1a` to `eu-west-1`. Now it should work.